# Nondeterministic automaton accepting only words whose first letter is identical to their next to last letter

Tags: automata

I was asked this question and could not come to the correct answer:

> Let $L$ be the language of all words over $\{a,b\}$ where the first letter is identical to the letter that is next to last. (Pay attention – every word with length 2 is in the language.)
>
> Sketch a nondeterministic automaton that accepts this language.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you want to make states $x/y/z$  which mean that $x$ is the first symbol of the word, $y$ is the second to last symbol seen, and $z$ is the last symbol seen.

I will show you half of the final machine, the one for words starting with $a$. Note that "!a" here means any symbol not equal to a, or no symbol at all.

[image: fsm]

Comment: Since the automaton for this question is allowed to be undeterministic, perhaps an intuitive appraoch would be to make a straightforward automaton for $a\Sigma^* a \Sigma$ ?

Comment: @HendrikJan Not quite, that would fail $aa$ or $ab$. But I'm sure you can get something more compact using non-determinism, I just usually prefer DFAs if I can see a solution with them as I find them easier to reason about.

Comment: Completely agree! For many problems determinism is the approach that leads to a solution that makes it clear what the automaton is "remembering", and proofs will be easier. However, when asked for an automaton for "strings with subword $aabab$" it is good to have the nondeterministic variant available, unless you want to implement KnuthMorrisPrat. It is not about compactness in this case (it will only save a single state.)

Comment: @HendrikJan That one wasn't too hard :P https://i.imgur.com/dr6HUX1.png